# JS Appended script tag executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically add a Google Analytics tag to a webpage. Initially I was using jQuery to do this and it worked fine. This is what my js using jQuery:

```
(function() {
if (typeof window.jQuery !== 'undefined' && typeof window.$ !== 'undefined') {
    var gtmHeadCode = "<!-- Google Tag Manager -->" +
        "<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':" +
        "new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]," +
        "j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=" +
        "'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);" +
        "})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>" +
        "<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->";

    var gtmBodyCode = "<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->" +
        "<noscript><iframe src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX'" +
        "height='0' width='0' style='display:none;visibility:hidden'></iframe></noscript>" +
        "<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->";

    if (jQuery('script[src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXX"]').length === 0) {
        jQuery('head').prepend(gtmHeadCode);
        jQuery('body').prepend(gtmBodyCode);
    }
}
}());
```

This worked perfectly. The gtmHeadCode would append the script tag and execute the js inside adding the other header tags for google tag manager that were necessary.

I decided to move away from this as some of the sites did not have jQuery and moved to a pure js approach which looked something like this:
     (window.addEventListener('load', function() {

```
    var gtmHeadCode = "<!-- Google Tag Manager -->" +
        "(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':" +
        "new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]," +
        "j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=" +
        "'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);" +
        "})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');" +
        "<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->";

    var gtmBodyCode = "<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->" +
        "<iframe src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXX'" +
        "height='0' width='0' style='display:none;visibility:hidden'></iframe>" +
        "<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->";

if (document.querySelectorAll('[src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX"]').length == 0) {
    var headTag = document.createElement('script');
    var bodyTag = document.createElement('noscript');
    headTag.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); 

    headTag.innerHTML += gtmHeadCode;
    bodyTag.innerHTML += gtmBodyCode;
    document.head.insertBefore(headTag, document.head.firstChild);
    document.body.insertBefore(bodyTag, document.body.firstChild);
}
}));
```

The problem I'm having here is the original `script` tag appends to the DOM head but the js does not seem to run? Why when appended with the jQuery prepend it worked fine but does not with the `insertBefore` in JS?

Comment: The jQuery library strips `<script>` blocks from HTML content and runs them itself. The browser won't do that for you.

Comment: I see, So would I run this code after it's appended then?

Comment: Why not just put the code in an ordinary function and call it when you want it to run?

Comment: I'm injecting google anayltics tags into a client site. Needs these to be appended in the header on load of page.